# Magento, how to override community controller in local codepool

Tags: php, magento, controller, overriding, extend

I would like to override AW Blog BlogController from Community to my local_MyCompany folder to modified the saveAction method. Can someone help me please.

Here is path for community controller class:

```
app\code\community\AW\Blog\controllers\Manage\BlogController.php
```

And here is my local_Business path:

```
require_once 'AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php';

class MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Manage_BlogController extends AW_Blog_Manage_BlogController
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        echo 'hello'; die();
    }

}
```

Here is my config.xml file content :

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyAwBlog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyCompany_MyAwBlog>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <myawblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MyCompany_MyAwBlog</module>
                <frontName>myawblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </myawblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <rewrite>        
        <mycompany_myawblog_blog_manage_blogcontroller>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/blog/manage_blog/#]]></from>
            <to>/myawblog/blog_manage_blog/</to>
        </mycompany_myawblog_blog_manage_blogcontroller>
    </rewrite>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <myawblog>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>MyCompany_MyAwBlog</module>
                <frontName>admin_myawblog</frontName>
            </args>
        </myawblog>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Controller file

```
require_once 'AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php';

class MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Manage_BlogController extends AW_Blog_Manage_BlogController
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        echo 'hello'; die();
    }

}
```

2) Config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <myawblog>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <MyCompany_MyAwBlog before="AW_Blog">MyCompany_MyAwBlog</MyCompany_MyAwBlog>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </myawblog>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

**Update for the Admin controller :**

Try following -

1) Controller file

```
<?php
require_once 'AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php';

class MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Manage_BlogController extends AW_Blog_Manage_BlogController
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        echo 'Hi'; 
        die();
    }
}
```

2) config.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <myawblog before="AW_Blog">MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Adminhtml</myawblog>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**NOTE :**

1) `require_once 'AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php';`

above mentioned controller path should be correct admin controller path. Same for the second point for the path after extends keyword.

2) `class MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Manage_BlogController extends AW_Blog_Manage_BlogController`

**Reference URL** [SUPEE-6788 TECHNICAL DETAILS](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Comment: It's not working, my controller's edit action is never called

Comment: @ Muk, no I get no error and no 404 page. The community action method is still called

Comment: @JPBernard You mentioned two controllers in your question admin as well as front end.For which one you are getting this? Have you tried to remove rewite from -to section from your xml.  Could you update the question with the clean code where you do not have commented lines?

Comment: @ Muk, I just edited my question, is this clearer? And by the way, it's for the backend

Comment: @JPBernard which version of Magento are you using/

Comment: @ Muk I'm using the 1.9.1.0 version

Comment: @ Muk That still does not go through my controller

Comment: @JPBernard Can you update your question with the directory path of the AW admin controller

Comment: @ Muk I just get it, thank you for your support
I juste updated the config.xml as it :
`<admin>
<routers>
            <blog_admin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompany_MyAwBlog_Blog</module>
                    <frontName>blog_admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </blog_admin>
        </routers>
    </admin>`

Comment: @ Muk Seriously? How am I going to do when I go to Magento 1.9.2.2 ?

Comment: Check my answer and see magento 1.9.2.2 release notes

Comment: @ Muk But in this way will I need to put the content of the Block folder in a folder Adminhtml?

Answer (score 0):

The initial answer provided by Muk doesn't worked for me (frontend controller override).

But with replacing the node just after  from  to , it works.

Because  is the rewrited route. But the goal here is to catch the base route, means .

So the final config.xml anwser that worked for me is:

```
<frontend>
<routers>
    <awblog>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <MyCompany_MyAwBlog before="AW_Blog">MyCompany_MyAwBlog</MyCompany_MyAwBlog>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </awblog>
</routers>
```